# Removing AWS default beanstalk page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have not been able to find much help on the topic of removing the AWS Elastic Beanstalk default page that shows.  The AWS URL: `wp-env(.....).elasticbeanstalk.com`

In my rails app, I have the root set to `root :to => 'posts#index'` but when I visit my AWS URL, I get the default page, instead of the Posts Index for my app.

The only way I seem to be able to get the URL to point to another "index" page is to create a static index.html page in my /Public folder.  I obviously don't want to do that.

Any solutions for this?

Thanks.

EDIT:  Maybe there is another line I need to specify in my routes.rb?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Take a look at the comments in your routes.rb file, there is a commented line saying you should remove the file: public/index.html

Be careful how you remove it, though! I did it the wrong way and it caused all sorts of havoc.

```
$ rm public/index.html

$ git add --all (to ensure removed files get removed)
$ git commit -am "removed the index file"
$ git push
$ git aws.push
```

This worked for me.

Good luck!